# how to capture a child pattern in a parent pattern

Tags: python-3.x, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following pattern (used with `re.DOTALL`) and text

```
(?P<year>20\d{2}).*?(?P<currency>RMB\d{1,3}(\W\d{3})*)
```

```
The financial statements for 2019 prepared in accordance with Accounting Standards for Business Enterprises by
the Group were audited by Grant Thornton (Special General Partnership). The Company paid the auditor in aggregate
RMB2,500,000 and RMB800,000 in respect of financial statements audit and non-audit services in relation to internal
control for 2018 respectively. The financial statements for 2019 prepared in accordance with Accounting Standards for Business Enterprises by
the Group were audited by Grant Thornton (Special General Partnership). The Company paid the auditor in aggregate
RMB2,500,000 and RMB800,000 in respect of financial statements audit and non-audit services in relation to internal
control for 2019 respectively.
```

it gives the following result.

```
Match 1
Named groups
currency    RMB2,500,000
year    2019
All groups
1.  2019
2.  RMB2,500,000
3.  ,000
Match 2
Named groups
currency    RMB2,500,000
year    2018
All groups
1.  2018
2.  RMB2,500,000
3.  ,000
```

but I want to have all the currency amount in the respective year, the desired result is the following

```
Match 1
Named groups
currency    RMB2,500,000
currency    RMB800,000
year    2019
All groups
1.  2019
2.  RMB2,500,000
3.  ,000
4. RMB800,000
5. ,000
Match 2
Named groups
currency    RMB2,500,000
currency    RMB800,000
year    2018
All groups
1.  2018
2.  RMB2,500,000
3.  ,000
4. RMB800,000
5. ,000
```

how may I do so?
here is the [link](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3FP%3Cyear%3E20%5Cd%7B2%7D).*%3F(%3FP%3Ccurrency%3ERMB%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%5CW%5Cd%7B3%7D)*)&test_string=The%20financial%20statements%20for%202019%20prepared%20in%20accordance%20with%20Accounting%20Standards%20for%20Business%20Enterprises%20by%0Athe%20Group%20were%20audited%20by%20Grant%20Thornton%20(Special%20General%20Partnership).%20The%20Company%20paid%20the%20auditor%20in%20aggregate%0ARMB2%2C500%2C000%20and%20RMB800%2C000%20in%20respect%20of%20financial%20statements%20audit%20and%20non-audit%20services%20in%20relation%20to%20internal%0Acontrol%20for%202018%20respectively.%20The%20financial%20statements%20for%202019%20prepared%20in%20accordance%20with%20Accounting%20Standards%20for%20Business%20Enterprises%20by%0Athe%20Group%20were%20audited%20by%20Grant%20Thornton%20(Special%20General%20Partnership).%20The%20Company%20paid%20the%20auditor%20in%20aggregate%0ARMB2%2C500%2C000%20and%20RMB800%2C000%20in%20respect%20of%20financial%20statements%20audit%20and%20non-audit%20services%20in%20relation%20to%20internal%0Acontrol%20for%202019%20respectively.&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=1&verbose=0) for the regex

Comment: You can add an optional group `(?P<year>20\d{2}).*?(?P<currency>RMB\d{1,3}(\W\d{3})*(?: and (RMB\d{1,3}(\W\d{3})*))?)` https://regex101.com/r/mxiGGd/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird what happen if I will be multiple currency numbers for a year e.g.`2019 foo RMB111,111 bar RMB111,111 bar RMB111,111 bar RMB111,111`?

Comment: The pattern is not dynamic, then you would have to use multiple optional groups. How do you know which year is the one you need, because there are multiple in this sentence `in respect of financial statements audit and non-audit services in relation to internal
control for 2018 respectively. The financial statements for 2019 prepared in accordance with Accounting Standards for Business Enterprises by
the Group were audited by Grant Thornton (Special General Partnership).`